# How to set the attributes of the create method reading data from a model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, repository-pattern

I have two tables that a related of which is the Request table and Project table. When you go to the lists of requests(Index) there is a link next to each record called Convert that when you navigate it some of the values from that record must set to the view of creating the Project like the RequestDate= start_date and close_date=end_date .

Project Controller

```
public ActionResult Convert(int ID)
        {
            var model = new AddProjectView();
            model.ReqNumber = ID;
            ViewBag.ProjectType = new SelectList(db.ProjectTypes, "Type", "Type");
            ViewBag.Size = new SelectList(db.ProjectSizes, "Size", "Size");
            ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(db.ProjectStatuses, "Status", "Status");
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Convert(AddProjectView model)
        {
            var bus = new ProjectBusiness();
            bus.Insert(model);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Request View Index

This is where i will navigate the Convert link then it should direct me to the project action method with the values i need ,getting them with the Request number(ReqNumber).

```
@model IEnumerable<Request> // assumed this is what the model is
foreach(var request in Model)
{
  .... // Display some property(s) of request
  @Html.ActionLink("Convert", "Project", new { ID = request.ReqNumber}) // pass the ID of the request to the controller
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach(var request in Model)
{  
    @Html.ActionLink("Convert", "Convert", "MyControllerName", new { id = request.ReqNumber }, null)
}
```

and your Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Convert(int? id)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: It is giving me following error:                                                The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'ID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method on the project controller

Comment: this means that you call Convert(int ID) with no parameters, please, try my edited example with `null` in the `ActionLink()`